# Checking session for empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables

I am using the codeigniter framework. I have session set in `$this->session->userdata('sess_place')` but I cannot echo using `if` condition. Maybe my `if` condition is wrong?

```
$pl = $this->session->userdata('sess_place');

if(isset($pl) && $pl = TRUE) {
   echo $pl;
}
else {
   echo "Select your city";
}
```

Comment: I think you made a typo here: `$pl = TRUE` use `==`

Comment: Are you sure you saved `TRUE` as a value in your session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used assign operater(=) instead of ==, which is wrong. Try this:

```
$pl = $this->session->userdata('sess_place');
if(isset($pl) && $pl == true) // and also no need of isset($pl) here jusy if($pl == TRUE) is enough
  {
   echo $pl;
  }
else
  {
    echo "Select your city";
  }
```

Comment: I just edited my question. I tried this also and it didn't worked for me.

Comment: in that case you might be assigning something else for sess_place, just echo $p1 and see what is the value is printing. if($p1) is enough condition here.

Comment: he he, I already mention that in the answer buddy, anyway enjoy! :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
$pl = $this->session->userdata('sess_place');
if(!empty($pl)) {
   echo $pl;
} else {
   echo "Select your city";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch data from the session. If it returns something other than false, it must be set.Try with -

```
if ($this->session->userdata('sess_place')) {
    echo $this->session->userdata('sess_place');
} else {
    echo "Select your city";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you storing Boolean value in session then try this.

```
$pl = $this->session->userdata('sess_place');
if(isset($pl) && $pl === true) // this checks value and its data type
{
   echo "Got it";
}
else
{
    echo "Select your city";
}
```